# Refresh gridview in ViewPager fragment after adding photo in MainActivity

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I would like to refresh my gridview in one of my view pager fragment once I have added an image through the function in main acitivty.

I do not know how to access to the gridview and adapter in the fragment from main activity , and hence I cannot use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and gridview.invalidateViews() .

Main Activity (fragment activity) - Fragment (ViewPager) - Fragment A, Fragment B, Fragment C

Add image function is in main acitivty, but gridview is in fragment A.

Please help.

Comment: post pager adapter and other related code

Comment: checkout this article https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html